# Error while trying to aggregate reduce with projectionoperation in springboot mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, reduce, projection

I want write following mongo query in spring

```
db.getCollection('mydb').aggregate([
{$match: {tag :"123"}},
{$group: {_id:"$tag" , message:{$addToSet: "$message"}},
  { $project: {
    "tag": "$tag",
    "message": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$message",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

few sample document in mydb collection looks like this

```
    doc1: {
     tag:"123",
    message: [{msg1},{msg2}]
    }
    doc2:{
     tag:"123",
    message: [{msg3},{msg4}, {msg5}]
    }
```

My objective is to group by tag and merge the message fields in to single array.
output:

```
    {
    tag:"123",
    message: [{msg1},{msg2},{msg3},{msg4}, {msg5}]
    }
```

In spring I tried ,

```
        List<AggregationOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<>();
        MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("tag").is("123"));
        GroupOperation groupingStage = group(Fields.fields("tag"))
                .first("tag").as("tag")
                .push("message").as("message")
             
        ArrayOperators.Reduce reduce = ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf("message")
                .withInitialValue(new ArrayList<>())
                .reduce(ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.arrayOf("$$value")
                        .concat("$$target");
       ProjectionOperation projectionOperation =project("tag").and(reduce).as("message");
        operationList.add(matchStage);
        operationList.add(groupingStage);
        operationList.add(projectionOperation);
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(operationList);
        AggregationResults<SomeClass> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,"mydb", SomeClass.class)

 

       This gives exception
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference '$$value'!
            at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:100)
            at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:72)
            at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AbstractAggregationExpression.unpack(AbstractAggregationExpression.java:73)
```

Without project operation it works fine but the result I get is not desired.. something like below

```
 {
    tag:"123",
    message: [[{msg1},{msg2}],
             [{msg3},{msg4}, {msg5}]]
 }
```

Comment: `.reduce(ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.arrayOf($$value)...`: I think the error message says something is wrong with the usage of `'$$value'`. The API says: During evaluation of the in expression the variable references `ArrayOperators.Reduce.Variable.THIS` and `ArrayOperators.Reduce.Variable.VALUE` are available.

Comment: Use the above method is correct, or u can go something with Bson. Eg `p->new Document("$project", new Document("tage","$tags").append("message",new Document("$reduce",new Document("input","$message").append("initialValue",[]).append(.....).....))`

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the $reduce entirely by using $unwind:

```
db.getCollection('mydb').aggregate([
  {$match: {tag :"123"}},
  {$unwind: "$message"},
  {$group: {_id:"$tag" , message:{$addToSet: "$message"}},
  { $project: {
    "_id": 0
    "tag": "$_id",
    "message": 1
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. in reality few more field for which I needed to get the sum over docs, So I had to modify your solution a bit. But your solution helped me to find the solution.